# Dual data type of specific column as per different selection?

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 column "Order Quantity"(data type whole no) and "Product"(data type text). Now what I want, when I select ProductA the datatype of "Order Quantity" column should be decimal otherwise in whole number. I Tried a lot but I failed to resolve my issue.
Plz anyone help me regarding this,

Input:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Objective:
For ProductA "Order Quantity" data type should be in decimal and rest of the Product(B,C and D) data type should be display in Whole number

Is it possible can we display mixed data type in specific column as per selection of Product? E.g. I applied this query but it doesn't work

- newvar=Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type",[Order Quantity],
  each [Product]<>"A", Number.Type([Order
  Quantity]))

Output screen:
[image]

Comment: Cant you just set a custom format in the excel sheet? I dont think this is a PQ issue

Comment: @horseyride I'm getting data from API can you help me regarding this how can I do in PowerBI Power Query?

Comment: What do you mean by selection? Active cell (highlighted by cursor) ?

Comment: @MichalPalko I have updated PFA the screenshot of output screen what I want to achieve for E.g. we have 2 columns name "Product" & "OrderQuantity" data is being displaying in matrix I want dual data type display in "Order quantity"  column where Product(Semifinished)=datatype display in decimal form otherwise display in whole number data type.

Comment: In general, the only way to display multiple data type formatting in a single column is to store it as text after applying the formatting rules you want. This can cause problems when you want to aggregate the column values though.